# PHP: can one determine the parent array's name and key from a reference to an array element?

Tags: php, arrays, reference

let's assume we have an array like this

```
$arr=array(array('a'=>1,'b'=>2),array('c'=>3,'d'=>4));
```

and a reference to one of its elements

```
$element=&$arr[1]['c'];
```

My question is is it possible to get back to the original array using the reference alone?
That is to get back to the parent array in some way without knowing it by name... This would be useful to me in a more complex scenario.

Comment: This question makes a case for the need of an `is` operator in PHP.  If you can assign a reference, there really should be a way of easily (and non-intrusively) testing whether you've done so.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's certainly not possible. Being a "reference" (as PHP calls it; it's actually a copy inhibitor) doesn't help at all in that matter. You'll have to store the original array together with the element.

```
$elArrPair = array(
    "container" => $arr,
    "element"   => &$arr[1]['c'],
);
```

This way you can change the element with `$elArrPair["element"] = $newValue` and still be able to access the container.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get from `$element` to `$arr`. You can use `in_array()` of course, but nothing about `$element` contains a reference to `$arr`.

Answer (score 0):

You copy the contect from one variable to another, nothing else, there is no connection between the two variables.

Comment: There most certainly *can be* a "connection".  `$b['proof'] =& $a; $a = 'see?'  print $b['proof'];`.  Now, that doesn't mean you can ever *know* that `$a` is also being referred to as `$b['proof']`, but there's an obvious link between the two.

Comment: well, if only that would have been what this question was about, clearly you can save a reference in an Element of an array, or any other variable, and access the content of the variable the reference points to ...

Comment: Not just access.  *Change*.  The two variables basically become names for the same object.  To say "there is no connection" is oversimplifying in the extreme.